# Quelle est la différence entre «car» et «parce que» ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, conjonctions

Je sais que les deux sont utilisés pour dire *pourquoi*, la raison, dans une réponse. Par exemple:

> « Pourquoi […] ?
>   —  Parce que […] »

Quand dois-je utiliser l'un plutôt que l'autre ? Sont-ils interchangeables ? Y a-t-il une différence de registre ?

Comment: En ce qui me concerne la différence essentielle est qu'on apprend aux enfants à dire *car*. Du coup j'ai tendance à associer l'usage de *car* au langage des enfants entre cinq et onze ans.

Comment: *parce que* n'est pas une instruction LISP valide ?

Comment: +1 pour @RomainVALERI. ;-) Mais je dirais *fonction* et non pas *instruction*. `car` etait une instruction machine pour la premiere implementation de Lisp, mais pour Lisp meme c'est une fonction.

Comment: The answers below about the different parts of speech are excellent. "Car" is a coordinating conjunction tandis que "parce que" is a subordinating conjunction or, as I learned it, a [conjunctive "locution"](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/conjonctif) ("locution" meaning "we don't have a better term for that group of words"!). To add a usage note: it may be that "car" is even rarer/more formal in Québec than in France, but in Ontario I hear "car" used in quite casual contexts among Francophones. "Je suis rentré car j'avais oublié mes clés." As if it were an equivalent of English "cuz", perhaps..

Comment: (Whereas if you look at the Canadian anthem, you'll find "car" in a more poetic context: "Ô Canada ! Terre de nos aïeux / Ton front est ceint de fleurons glorieux ! / Car ton bras sait porter l'épée, / Il sait porter la croix !" Incidentally, here it does begin a sentence, though that depends on whether you treat those exclamation marks in the [Wikipédia transcription](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%94_Canada) as really ending the sentences or as just the fruit of an overexcited lyricist.)

Comment: Pour ce qui est de la différence de registre, c'est évident: de nos jours, en France, « parce que » est plus clair et donc à préférer pour un écrit scientifique. De même en anglais, on préférera « because » à « since ». Pour la clarté.

Comment: Ils ne sont pas riches, car ils n'ont guère travaillé. car=as. They are not rich as they have hardly  worked. Is "as" the same as "because"?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Une des grandes différences est que ["parce que" est une conjonction de subordination](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parce%20que) et introduit donc une proposition subordonnée. Ainsi "parce que" peut être utilisé en début de phrase. Il indique une cause, un motif.

> Je n'ai pas pu venir, parce que j'ai eu un accident.

En revanche, ["car" est une conjonction de coordination](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/car) et ne peut pas commencer une phrase*, il ne peut que relier deux propositions. "Car" soutient un jugement, indique une raison.

> Je n'ai pas pu venir car j'ai eu un accident.

"Puisque" est une conjonction de subordination aussi. Il peut démarrer une phrase et indique une justification ou explication généralement évidente.

> Puisque j'ai eu un accident, tu comprends bien que je ne pouvais pas venir!

Edit: 
* Le lien indique que le point peut parfois être utilisé avant car, pour maintenir le style linguistique employant des phrases courtes dans un roman par exemple. Techniquement cela fait de car un début de phrase, mais il y a tout de même la proposition qui le précède.

Comment: Tu as dit: « *"Parce que" peut-être utiliser en début de phrase* » et « *"car" […] ne peut pas commencer une phrase* », mais tes exemples sont les mêmes... Donc ou est-elle la différence ?

Comment: On ne peut pas dire "car j'ai eu un accident, je n'ai pas pu venir." par contre cela fonctionne avec parce que. Et puisque aussi.

Comment: Aah, très bien! :) Merci beaucoup.

Comment: En plus de _puisque_, on peut utiliser _comme_ il me semble : _Comme j'ai eu un accident, tu comprends bien que je ne pouvais pas venir ! _

Comment: Effectivement: parce que = car, puisque = comme, les 4 sont très similaires, avec une légère différence: puisque/comme indique que la première action se réalise concrètement, et provoque la seconde, alors que parce que/car indique une causalité plus générale.

Comment: C'est n'est pas très claire, je pense que il faut que tu modifies ton premier exemple comme ça: Parce que j'ai eu un accident, je n'ai pas pu venir.

Comment: Avez-vous des sources? L'idée générale me semble juste, mais pour une telle coupe de cheveu en quatre, il serait intéressant d'avoir l'opinion d'un Littré ou autre.

Comment: J'ai ajouté les liens vers le CNRTL.

Answer (score 9):

Au Québec, on utilise principalement *parce que*. Il n'y a pas de différence de signification avec *car*, c'est simplement que *car* n'est pas très utilisé (à mon avis c'est probablement dû à la façon dont on prononce nos *a* : prononcer *car* correctement requerrait plus d'effort que *parce que* et aurait l'air étrange).

Aussi, il ne faut pas être surpris d'entendre *à cause que*. Cette utilisation n'est faite qu'à l'oral.

> Je n'ai pas pu venir à cause que j'ai eu un accident.

Comment: Arrhhhh :-) - C'est fréquent au Québec? En France, _Je n'ai pas pu venir à cause que j'ai eu un accident._ ce serait plus considéré comme incorrect, voire une horreur à éviter à tout prix, bien qu'on l'entende, évidemment.

Comment: @Frank C'est trés fréquent :)

Comment: Il faut que je m'en souvienne pour la prochaine fois que je serais à Montréal :-)

Comment: @Frank «M. Gillenormand, lequel était on ne peut plus vivant en  1831,  était  un  de  ces  hommes  devenus  curieux  à  voir uniquement **à cause qu’ils** ont longtemps vécu, et qui sont étranges parce qu’ils ont jadis ressemblé à tout le monde et  que  maintenant  ils  ne  ressemblent  plus  à  personne.» —Victor Hugo, Les Misérables

Comment: @Feelew - bizarre - à mes oreilles, cela ne sonne pas bien du tout. Il faudrait voir la fréquence au cours du temps aussi.

Comment: @Frank Oui, ça avait écorché mes habitudes aussi quand j'avais lu ça. Mais comme c'était Hugo, j'ai cherché et ai trouvé que c'était bien vivant jusqu'à la fin du XIXe, puis que ça a un peu passé de mode après, **à cause que** ça sonne un peu rugueux. Il existe quelques utilisations au XXe siècle, dont au moins une d'André Gide. _Le Bon usage_ prend le temps d'en discuter un peu (je n'ai pas le numéro exact, mais c'est facile à trouver avec l'index).

Comment: Comme souvent, cher @Frank, c'est au Québec qu'on parle le meilleur français, ``«Soyez persuadés que c'est à cause que vous êtes si exactes à les veiller [les pensionnaires de Saint-Cyr] qu'elles sont si aisées à conduire, et qu'aussitôt que vous cesserez de les observer, elles deviendront libertines (Françoise d'Aubigné, marquise de MAINTENON, Entret. sur l'éduc. juin 1704)»``

Answer (score 4):

Une petite recherche dans le TFL donne à [Car](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/car), remarque 2 :

> Rem. 2. Car/Parce que, Car/Puisque. Contrairement à car, parce que et
> puisque peuvent être utilisés après certaines conj. de coordination :
> et, mais, ni parce que ou et, mais, ni puisque;  de même ils peuvent
> être repris par que : parce que... et que ou puisque... et que.
>
> D'autre part, parce que peut introduire une prop. en réponse à la
> question pourquoi?, s'employer derrière des adv. tels que précisément,
> justement, uniquement, seulement, surtout..., après le tour uniceptif
> ne... que et le présentatif c'est, tous emplois impossibles avec car.
> La conj. car qui introduit une explication peut avoir la même valeur
> que puisque, qui garantit le bien-fondé véridique de l'énoncé.
>
> Noter ds l'ex. suiv. la reprise de car par puisque : ... toute
> l'inclinaison (générale) du corps en avant dénonce, trahit ce que je
> suis, car je le deviens, puisque je le deviens : un paysan (...).
> L'inclinaison commençante générale vers la terre nourricière, vers la
> terre mère, vers la terre tombeau. Péguy, Victor-Marie,Comte Hugo,
> 1910, p. 672.

Answer (score 4):

> Au Louisiane, nous-autres on dit "par rapport que" quand on est après
>   raconter quelque chose + subordinate-clause. Et quand on peut aussi
>   utiliser "à cause de." Tandis que, parce que est utilisé raconter une
>   raison en réponse à la question.

[ En Louisiane, nous disons « par rapport que » lorsque nous expliquons quelque chose pour introduire une proposition subordonnée. Ainsi que là où on pourrait utiliser « à cause de ». Alors que *parce que* est utilisé pour introduire une raison en réponse à une question posée. ]

Comment: Bonjour ! Merci, avez-vous svp. un exemple qui permette de comprendre la nuance du cas où vous dites que _parce que_ sert à introduire une _raison_ ; quelle nuance y a-t-il entre l'introduction d'une subordonnée et l'introduction d'une raison ds. une réponse pour vous ? Je vous invite par ailleurs à jeter un coup d’œil [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/20151/3177) pour une perspective différente sur le sujet. Merci !

Comment: Ce contenu a été modifié selon l'intention initiale qui motivait une récompense et une modification antérieure et qui n'aurait jamais du être supprimée. Il s'agit de rendre plus accessible un contenu unique. Merci.

Comment: Je ne sais pas si Réagan reviendra, mais c'est très intéressant comme remarque. J'y comprend que si je raconte quelque chose, je rétro-justifie en introduisant avec «par rapport que»: «Je visite ma voisine chaque matin avant de quitter pour mon travail, par rapport qu'elle n'est pas complètement autonome et n'a personne pour l'aider le matin». Si qqn me demande pourquoi je visite ma voisine chaque matin, alors j'introduis avec «parce qu'elle n'est pas complètement autonome et...».

Comment: Je crois avoir déjà entendu ce genre de tournure dans mon enfance, mais ça semble s'être raréfié et être passé au statut de relique du passé aujourd'hui. Comme enfant, je prêtais moins d'attention à ces choses, mes interractions avec les adultes étaient aussi plus ponctuelles, et mes souvenirs ne sont pas des plus vivides concernant ce point en particulier, mais ça sonne quasi-familier, comme une odeur oubliée qui ressurgit et fait remonter des images et des situations du passé.

Comment: *Par rapport que* et *rapport que* existent aussi au Québec et, je présume, en Acadie. Je ne suis pas certain s'il y a une différence de sens avec *parce que*.