# What is the difference between "car" and "parce que"?

Tags: conjonctions

What is the difference between *car* and *parce que*? And when to use it? It seems like both words translates to "because". In effect, I am asking if both are interchangeable.

Comment: There's an answer to that question here : http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/quelle-est-la-difference-entre-car-et-parce-que.  Just say if you need the answer translated.