# Par rapport que, rapport (à ce) que, à cause que : causalité objective/subjective, autres nuances ?

Tags: conjonctions, québec, locutions, france, registre

> Il a de faux cheveux, *rapport à ce qu*'il est rouge. (Balzac)
>   D'abord essuie-toi les pieds, *rapport au* tapis. (Bernanos)

Il s'agit de locutions conjonctives en langue populaire exprimant la causalité dont on traite au LBU14 (§§1139, 1047, 1073 : omission de la préposition *par* avec *par rapport à*, l'idée de la comparaison, qui avait pris une nuance de cause, de manière populaire, à l'oral) ; au [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/rapport/66517/difficulte) (*rapport à*, qu'on suggère de remplacer par *à cause de* entre autres) ; puis au *TLFi* où on relève de manière contemporaine deux emplois régionaux s'appliquant au Québec :

> ♦ ***Par rapport que***, loc. conj., pop. et région. (Québec, etc.). **Parce
>   que.** *Je ne suis pas venu par rapport qu'une affaire imprévue m'en a
>   empêché* (J.B.L., [*Gasc. corr.*](https://archive.org/stream/lesgasconismesco00desg#page/352/mode/2up/search/par+rapport+que), 1823).
>  ♦ *Rapport à*
>   (pop.). À propos de. [...] **Rapport (à ce) que**, loc. conj., pop. et
>   région. (Québec). **Vu que, étant donné que, puisque.** [Une grisette:]
>   (...) *je l'ai attendue dans la rue* [votre dame], *rapport à ce qu'un
>   aimable homme (...) m'avait prévenue que j'avais une madame Jules pour
>   rivale* (Balzac, *Ferragus*, 1833, p. 87).
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé*, TLFi, [rapport](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rapport), avec mon soulignement ]

Troisièmement, on a aussi au [Québec](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3815), encore de manière populaire, [*à cause que*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cause/1) pour parce que, vieilli ailleurs depuis Bescherelle (1845), que l'on dit vivant à Paris, entre autres (LBU14, §1139 note H). Parfois on l'utilise à dessein : « Écrire, c'est un plus gros effort, à cause que la main est déjà lassée par toutes les polyphonies courantes. » (Barrès)

---

On peut comparer indirectement *parce que* et *puisque*, la cause objective répondant à la question *pourquoi* par opposition à la justification d'un propos qui précède ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/puisque/65020/difficulte)) ; *puisque* introduirait une « explication considérée comme évidente, déjà connue éventuellement des interlocuteurs » ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3501)).

---

- Au Québec, est-ce que la différence entre la cause objective (*par rapport que*, *à cause que*) et la cause plus subjective (*rapport que*) est sentie dans l'emploi de ces locutions à l'oral. Autrement dit, qu'est-ce qui motive l'emploi de l'une ou l'autre ; sont-elles exactement du même registre populaire ?
- Généralement à l'oral en français (causalité objective/subjective) comment perçoit-on la différence entre *parce que* et *puisque*, et qu'est-ce qui motive leur emploi ?
- À Paris, emploie-t-on toujours *à cause que* populairement à l'oral ?

Comment: Étant Parisien, je n'ai pratiquement jamais entendu *à cause que*

Comment: @Toto Merci pour l'info ! À l'entendre vous le percevez comme vieilli ou fautif ? Vous avez entendu une des deux locutions québécoises à Paris ?

Comment: De façon subjective, je le perçois plus fautif que vieilli. *Rapport à* est utilisé couramment mais *par rapport que* m'est totalement inconnu.

Answer (score 1):

Ne connaissant pas du tout le jargon québecois, je vais tâcher de répondre relatives à l'usage en France uniquement.

**Généralement à l'oral en français (causalité objective/subjective) comment perçoit-on la différence entre parce que et puisque, et qu'est-ce qui motive leur emploi ?**

Objectivement, je pense qu'en utilisant l'une ou l'autre, l'interlocuteur comprendra tout à fait le sens de la phrase sans trouver quelque chose bizarre.

Ceci étant, *parce que* s'utilise plutôt lorsque la raison donnée à l'interlocuteur lui est inconnue :

> Je pars dans dix minutes, parce que j'ai rendez-vous avec ma sœur.

Ici, j'apprends à la personne à laquelle je parle que j'ai un rendez-vous.

> Je pars dans dix minutes, puisque j'ai rendez-vous avec ma sœur.

Ici, la personne sait que j'ai rendez-vous, et j'aurais pu également dire "*Comme tu le sais bien, je dois partir car j'ai rendez-vous avec ma soeur*".

---

**À Paris, emploie-t-on toujours *à cause que* populairement à l'oral ?**

Je n'ai jamais entendu cette formulation. Bien que je ne la trouve pas choquante, elle ne me paraît pas très naturelle pour du langage oral.