# How to say «it's because» in French?

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais

For example:

> – Tu as eu de bonnes notes ce semestre.
>
> – «It's because» j'ai étudié beaucoup.

I've heard non native speakers saying «C'est pourquoi» et «C'est parce que», but I think both sound strange. So, what's the correct way of saying this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On va faire simple : ***C'est parce que***

Car c'est cette locution qui annonce la **cause** quand *c'est pourquoi* annoncerait un effet, une conséquence.

Ici, *j'ai étudié beaucoup* représente la cause des bonnes notes.

Comme les bonnes notes sont symétriquement la conséquence de l'étude, on aurait ainsi pu dire :

*J'ai étudié beaucoup, c'est pourquoi j'ai eu des bonnes notes.*

Tu peux évidemment vouloir alambiquer ce *c'est parce que* :

- C'est en raison du fait que...
- Cela vient de ce que...
- C'est grâce au fait que...
  etc.

<sub>En marge de cette question, on considérera la remarque de Marc Glisse en commentaires qui suggère fort à propos d'inverser la position de *beaucoup.* On peut.</sub>

Comment: Even c'est que tout net

Comment: Au passage, j'inverserais "étudié" et "beaucoup" (ou j'utiliserais autre chose que "beaucoup"). Ça fait bizarre sinon.

Comment: @MarcGlisse : Oui! On peut effectivement. J'ai ajouté une note. Après... cela dépendra quand même de ce sur quoi le locuteur souhaite insister. Mais il est vrai que l'adverbe suit le plus souvent le verbe conjugué c'est à dire ici l'auxiliaire et donc se présentera, le plus souvent avant le participe passé.

Answer (score 3):

La confusion entre ***pourquoi*** (conséquence) et ***parce que*** (cause), qui est la forme attendue ici, est typique des locuteurs espagnols, italiens et portugais.

La raison en est que dans ces trois langues, d'une part on distingue peu voire pas les deux, respectivement ***porque***/**por qué** (espagnol), ***perché***/**perché** (italien) et ***porque***/**porquê** (portugais), et d'autre part l'équivalent de ***parce que*** est dans ces trois langues beaucoup plus proche phonétiquement parlant du ***pourquoi*** français.

Les locuteurs anglophones ou germanophones ne font pas cette erreur car ***why***/**because** et ***warum***/**den**|**weil**|**da** sont nettement distincts.

Comment: L'explication est plausible. Et le pseudo de l'OP pourrait pleinement la justifier ici en particulier. Il reste néanmoins, et deux autres contributions ici pourraient en témoigner, l'inconséquence est une raison générale et, plus spécifiquement, la traduction de la relation de cause à effet dans une langue étrangère.

Comment: @aCOSwt L'inconséquence de qui ?

Comment: De qui ???  Errrr ??? L'inconséquence **que** traduit la relation de cause à effet traduite évidemment!

Comment: Désolé, mais je ne vois pas où tu veux en venir avec cette [inconséquence](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/incons%C3%A9quence)...

Comment: Pas plus loin que le point final que j'avais mis à mon premier commentaire. Ici, je n'ai jamais parlé que de langue. Jamais de ceux qui la pratiquent. (J'espère que tu auras noté, dans le lien que tu me fournis... gracieusement que *C'est le propre du panthéisme de ne subsister que par une inconséquence à sa méthode* sans t'interroger sur l'inconséquence... de qui)

Comment: @aCOSwt Désolé, mais je ne comprends toujours pas ce que signifie *Il reste néanmoins l'inconséquence est une raison générale*. Tu as du oublier quelque chose.

Comment: S'il vous plait, "parce que" ou "car" - c'est quoi la difference?  Je suis anglais - quand dis-je "parce que" ou "car" si je dis "because" en anglais?  Dans votre derniere paragraphe, vous avez dit "car", et pas "parce que".

Comment: @Graham J'aurais pu utiliser *parce que* à la place de *car* dans cette phrase.  Il existe cependant une différence entre les deux. Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/quelle-est-la-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-car-et-parce-que

Comment: @jlliagre Merci!

Answer (score 1):

C'est dû au fait que,

Car

C'est attribuable à

C'est dû

Puisque

C'est à cause de

En raison de

Comment: Pour la même raison qu'indiquée dans mon commentaire à Lily : Non! *C'est la raison pour laquelle* ne convient pas ici. C'est la raison pour laquelle annonce **la conséquence**

Comment: *C'est ainsi que* n'introduit pas une cause mais une conséquence (ou une manière selon le contexte): *j'ai beaucoup étudié, c'est ainsi que j'ai eu de bonnes notes*.

Comment: Pas "puisque", qui ne s'emploie pas de cette façon grammaticale. Et "à cause" de implique que la causalité a un effet négatif. Par opposition à "grâce à".

Answer (score 0):

Comme beaucoup de chose en français, on ferait un sous-entendu en disant :

> - Tu as eu de bonnes notes ce semestre.
> - Oui, j'ai **beaucoup** étudié !

En mettant l'emphase sur le beaucoup grâce au ton de la voix et au langage non verbal.

Comment: Si un non francophone pose une question sur les mots je doute fort qu'il s'attende à une réponse sur le non verbal. Il cherche des expressions et des tournures pour enrichir son vocabulaire.

Comment: C'est pareil en anglais, on dit aussi cela, donc cette implication n'est pas propre au français.

Comment: Il pose clairement la question de comment on dit : 

_« So, what's the correct way of saying this? »_

Le non verbal est donc important, d’autant plus que le français est une langue où le contexte est plus important qu’en anglais.